# How to get return value of a subroutine in a perl script to bash

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have done a shell script that gets the output of a `.jar` file and assign in to a variable.

rewards_generator.sh

```
APP_ROOT=/home/testApps/
JAR=${APP_ROOT}ClusterGenerator/generator.jar

#get clusters
clusters=$(loadClusters $1)

for i in `echo $clusters | sed 's/,/ /g'`
do
    #pull cluster records from database and save query return status to $x
    x=$(/usr/IBM/WebSphere/ProcServer/java/bin/java ${JAR} ${i/-/_} 2>&1)
done
```

Basically, what I've done to the java app is to `System.out.print` the query return status. Then used the `2>&1` in bash in order to get into the output stream and assign the value to a shell script variable.

Now how can I get the return value of a perl script and assign it to a shell script variable? Is it the same as the one I've done above or is there any other approach to do this?

Comment: I have not yet tried doing it.

Comment: The `2>& 1` was not needed. `System.out` already *is* stdout, or fd 1.

Comment: Now to the core of your question: Your sample code is all about getting a value from inside a java application into the shell. Using $( ... ) for that is correct.  Next you mention the return value of a [perl] script.  In the shell, the exit status of the last command, be it script, builtin, or binary, is always available in the `$?` variable.  So please rephrase your question to clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks to record the output of an external command in a bash script.

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Execute the script, recording output to a variable
x=`/path/to/script.pl`

# Display or act on the output some time later
echo "script output: $x"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now how can I get the return value of a perl script and assign it to a shell script variable?

```
#! /bin/bash
perl script.pl
return_value=$?
```